# Writing a classification model as a function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, xgboost

Given a dataframe `df2` that looks like this:

```
rated_object     feature_1    feature_2    feature_n    rating
o1               2.02         0            90.40        0
o2               3.70         1            NaN          1
o3               3.45         0            70.50        1
o4               7.90         1            40.30        0
...
```

I wrote the following model:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

cols_to_drop = ['rated_object'] 
df2.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)

X = df2.drop('rating', axis=1)  
y = df2['rating'] 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)

model = XGBClassifier() 
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

I want to write it as a function, though, that takes the dataframe and `rated_object` as an input and returns the predicted rating. What I did was naively copy-pasting the code above into a function:

```
def function(df2, rated_object):…
```

But that even returned me an error on the `train_test_split()` line because “I got multiple values for argument test_size”, even if I copied it 1-to-1 from above.

I just want to input for example `function(df2, o4)` and get the predicted rating, is that possible?

Edit: this is what I did:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import pandas as pd

def predict_cn(df, rated_object):
    is_target = (df['rated_object'] == rated_object)
    target = df[is_target].iloc[0]
    cols_to_drop = ['rated_object'] 
    df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
    X = df.drop('rating', axis=1)  
    y = df['rating'] 
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)
    model = XGBClassifier() 
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    prediction=model.predict(target['rated_object'], verbose=False)
    return prediction
```

And the error when inputing, for example `predict_cn(df2, 'o3')`:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-08dcbb77df37> in <module>
----> 1 predict_cn(df2, 'o3')

<ipython-input-9-18667675e17b> in predict_cn(df, rated_object)
      6     X = df.drop('rating', axis=1)
      7     y = df['rating']
----> 8     X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)
      9     model = XGBClassifier()
     10     model.fit(X_train, y_train)

TypeError: train_test_split() got multiple values for argument 'test_size'
```

I know it is because `y` is of numeric type when I print it, but I tried writing it as `y = pd.DataFrame(df2['rating'])` and I still get the error.

Edit: new code and mock data to play around with:

```
from numpy import nan
data_mock = [['q1', 10.93, 20, 1, 0], ['q2', nan, 12, 0, 1], ['q3', 14.34, 30, 0, 1], ['q4', 12.93, 20, 0, 1], ['q5', nan, 62, 1, 0], ['q6', 14.34, 60, 0, 0], ['q7', 16.93, 28, 1, 1], ['q8', nan, 12, 1, 1], ['q9', 10.34, 50, 0, 0], ['q10', 10.93, 20, 0, 0], ['q11', nan, 57, 1, 1], ['q12', 89.34, 30, 0, 0]]
df_mock = pd.DataFrame(data_mock, columns = ['rated_object', 'feature_1', 'feature_2', 'feature_n', 'rating'])
def predict_cn(df, rated_object):
    df_copy=df.copy()
    is_target = (df_copy['rated_object'] == rated_object)
    target = df_copy[is_target].iloc[0]
    cols_to_drop = ['rated_object'] 
    df_copy.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
    X = df_copy.drop('rating', axis=1)  
    y = df_copy['rating']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)
    model = XGBClassifier() 
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test) 
    prediction=model.predict(target['questionId'], verbose=False)
    return prediction
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes it is possible.  Perhaps if you showed your exact function and the error stack trace it would be easier to make suggestions.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thank you, I edited. I know the cause of the error but I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.  Any difference with `y = df["rating"].values`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs It does make y an array, but I get the same error. I thought my function was modifying external data, so I tried making a copy of the original dataframe, but it still didn’t work.

Comment: And your original code at the top of your question works as expected?

Comment: Can you share the output of X, y if possible?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes, the original one does. I edited the question and provided the function (with the df.copy attempt) and a mock dataset.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal I edited the question and provided a mock dataset. The output of X and y were the same as when I was just writing the model separately, not within a function.

Comment: I don't get a `train_test_split` error when I run your code with the mock data.  Do you have the latest version of `scikit-learn`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I do. Did you also import `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`? Maybe here is the mistake...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is getting the features of the object that you want to predict.

Try this code.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import pandas as pd


dic = {
    'rated_object': ['o1', 'o2', 'o3', 'o4'],
    'feature_1': [2.02, 3.7, 3.45, 7.9],
    'feature_2': [0, 1, 0, 1],
    'feature_n': [90.4, None, 70.5, 40.3],
    'rating': [0, 1, 1, 0]
}


def predict_cn(df, target):
    # Get the row where target is located.
    targetdf = df.copy()  # do not modify df as we will use it in training
    targetdf = targetdf.loc[targetdf['rated_object'] == target]  # lookup target in column rated_object and return the row
    targetdf.drop(['rated_object', 'rating'], axis=1, inplace=True)  # drop unnecessary columns, we just need the features

    # Prepare training datasets.
    cols_to_drop = ['rated_object'] 
    df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)

    X = df.drop('rating', axis=1)  
    y = df['rating']
    X_train, _, y_train, _ = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)

    model = XGBClassifier()
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    prediction = model.predict(targetdf)

    return prediction


# Start
mydf = pd.DataFrame(dic)
target = 'o4'

pred = predict_cn(mydf, target)
print(f'prediction: {pred}')
```

Comment: How does this answer address the execution error?  See the Traceback in the question.

Comment: Your code is probably "fine".  I'm just wondering if the OP has some other issues since his errors seem not be reproducible.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I cannot reproduce that traceback. Did you try his code and able to reproduce that traceback? But I know what johnnydoe is up to. He wants to create a function and pass the dataframe and object value to predict, to this function and then return the prediction.

Comment: Your code works for the mock dataset, but when trying it out with my own it gives me the same error.

Comment: What do you mean by `when trying it out with my own` and what error message is this?

Comment: @ferdy with a big dataset that I had and the traceback error message was an in the original post. I now tried it in Google Colab and it works, if I run it once, but when I try it with another target it gives me the error "rated_object".

Comment: Did you still use your first `def predict_cn(df, rated_object):`? And it works once in google colab? Does the term `it works` you are able to reproduce the error or you are able to get the prediction without errors?

Comment: @johnnydoe Perhaps the `inplace` drops are destroying your original DataFrame?